# Jquery code cleanup

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to not have to write this 'twice'
See below where the function for #start_date and #end_date is exactly the same.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(function($){

        $("#start_date").datepicker({
            showButtonPanel: true,
            minDate: 1,
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
        });

        $("#end_date").datepicker({
            showButtonPanel: true,
            minDate: 1,
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
        });     

    });

</script>
```

Comment: Can you change HTML code ? If so just use a class instead of an id.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
jQuery(function($){

    $("#start_date, #end_date").datepicker({
        showButtonPanel: true,
        minDate: 1,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
    }); 

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LWQCE/

Or use a class:

```
(function($){

    $(".myDatePickers").datepicker({
        showButtonPanel: true,
        minDate: 1,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
    }); 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a comma in jQuery to select multiple ids.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(function($){

        $("#start_date, #end_date").datepicker({
            showButtonPanel: true,
            minDate: 1,
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
        }); 

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

I would not worry about this little amount of code duplication. Also, maybe you decide in a week to change one of the attributes, then you will be happy not to have refactored too much.

Especially in this very simple (and quite easy to read) code example, I'm tempted to apply the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28computer_programming%29) refactoring rule of thumb, which states that "the code can be copied once, but when the same code is used three times, it should be extracted into a new procedure".

Comment: Have you ever heard of [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) (don't repeat yourself)?